# Is there a timeframe that needs to pass before you can get shot with a zat gun again without dying?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, weapon

So right now I'm up to season 6 in Stargate SG1, and I've noticed the main crew gets zapped with a [zat'nik'tel](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Zat) A LOT. Shouldn't they be dead by now? I thought the second shot kills and the third causes the body to disappear. Did this change somewhere? Is there a period of time where if you don't get shot it wont kill you?

Comment: [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitch_hikers_guide_to_the_galaxy#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) minutes.  Beat you to it, @Xantec.

Comment: Consider this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6404/in-stargate-is-there-an-in-universe-explanation-of-the-cumulative-effect-of-zat/6405#6405

Comment: Wouldn't it be 38 minutes, SG's "42 minutes"? ;)

Answer (score 23):

There's probably a residual charge or something left in the body after one shot which takes time to dissipate. Adding a second charge from another shot would then be too much for the body to take, and hence leads to death for the target.

Of course, this then opens up questions on things like body mass... shouldn't a bigger person be able to absorb more hits than a smaller person?

Also - I think the ridiculousness of the weapon was lampshaded in the Wormhole X-Treme episode ;)

Comment: As a viewer, who never thought I could ask the question, I'd always assumed a minute or two was all that was needed.

Comment: I think your body mass thing makes sense, however there's also the concept that the zat's energy is probably really close to the threshold of death for a smaller person, and not closer to not killing a larger person on two shots (what I'm trying to say is that a smaller person would probably more likely die from one shot than a large person not dying from two shots, these are the Goa'ulds)

Comment: @DKuntz yeah, that was something I was trying to put across, but obviously not that well.

Comment: I don't know that body mass would have much of an impact.  I get the impression the zat was more about attacking a target's nervous system.  Sort of like futuristic tasers.  In cases like that, the response is more based on things which affect the nervous system, the same way a taser sometimes appears to have less affect on someone who is drunk than it does on a sober person.

Comment: In addition, you seem to build up a resistance to the Zats after being shot with them frequently.  Initially, it was lights out for SG-1 for a few hours any time they were struck.  More recently, the team has been able to function effectively seconds later, albeit apparently in extreme pain.

Comment: Also, the whole three-shots disappears you thing was ultimately ret-conned out, because someone realized just how ridiculous it was.

Comment: This was one of the problems that perpetually frustrated GM's for the RPG.  Eventually retconned away, never really mentioned after SG! got back from the 70's if I remember right, other than the Lampshading in Wormhole Extreme.

Comment: I think it is safe to say that body mass is a part of it, however small. One example we saw of the zat gun killing on the first shot was of Teal'c shooting the Sodan slug-infection creature in season 10, episode 5

Answer (score 4):

The writers realized this was a problematic idea.  As mentioned by others, they [hung a lantern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMBL4rzlZjQ) on their own bad ideas in the self-parody episode [Wormhole X-Treme!](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Wormhole_X-Treme!_%28episode%29)

> **Director**: The reality of the scene dictates there be dead aliens ... because you just killed them.
>
> **Head Writer**: We could always go back to the way it was in the script.
>
> **Director**: No we can't. We've already established that one shot stuns and two shots kills. Nick just shot everybody twice.
>
> **Martin**: So three shots disintegrates them!
>
> **Director**: Okay, you know what? I'm gonna pretend you didn't say that, because that is quite possibly the stupidest thing I've ever heard you say.

Comment: I always thought it was funny how that never came back. They used it way back in Season 2 when Jack shot the box of future stuff... but when sneaking around inside of ships they didn't shoot the bad guys three times to just make them disappear?

Answer (score 1):

It's one of those "Hitchcock-ian" things...left up to the viewer to decide the time frame...of course i'd go with my usual couple minutes rule. If they get shot once they got a couple minutes or so before they can be shot again as that is usually the case in most of those scenarios.